# cleartool command execution in Java

Tags: clearcase, jenkins-plugins

I want to execute cleartool command `cleartool lstype -kind -lbtype -s -inv \VoB` from Java applications. Later I need to import this plugin in Jenkins and only have to give the name of `VoB` as input argument. So far I tried to find out how such commands are implemented in **ClearCase Plugin** but unable to find a hint how I can implement it in my plugin. Does anybody have an idea how to proceed further or any previous implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround would be to execute the `cleartool` command in a `Runtime.exec()` Java process.
See for instance [this thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/401429/java/java/executing-cleartool-java):

```java
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd2);  

        // For normal stream reading  
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(  
                                new InputStreamReader(  
                                    p.getInputStream()));
```

Otherwise, the [latest versions of the Jenkins ClearCase plugin use `cleartool`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/clearcase-plugin/commit/aaf02015adff5ee47f63cac590a077594c24ac1d) ([issue JENKINS-15196](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15196)), so using a [`CleartoolCommand`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/clearcase-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/clearcase/command/CleartoolCommand.java) should work.
You can build any command you want, as shown in:

- [`hudson/plugins/clearcase/command/LsHistoryCommand`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/clearcase-plugin/blob/0e6dbfcaa44b0ae7644c25a7a050e9efbb6c05d4/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/clearcase/command/LsHistoryCommand.java#L75-L89)
- [`test/java/hudson/plugins/clearcase/command/LsHistoryCommandTest`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/clearcase-plugin/blob/master/src/test/java/hudson/plugins/clearcase/command/LsHistoryCommandTest.java).